# I have 3 PCs on the same WiFi. Why are 2 of their local IPs "192.168.1.x" but the 3rd PC is "192.168.56.x"?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

The third PC which has that `192.168.56.x` local IP is ALSO conveniently the only PC that I can't get to connect to my iPhone.

What is going on here? Is this meaningful in any way, that one PC has a different local IP format than the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one can definitively answer this question without knowing the specifics of your network.  Below are a couple of best guesses.

Guess 1:  There are 2 DHCP servers running on the network handing out different IP addresses.   If this is the case you should disable one of the DHCP servers.

Guess 2:  This machine has a static IP address assigned to it.  If the netmask is 255.255.255.0 this could cause issues.  If its 255.255.0.0 it should work anyway.

Guess 3:  You are using some kind of network isolation feature which is isolating WIFI devices (maybe in a guest network, or maybe all devices) by assigning the IP addresses from a different range to devices on the LAN, and using firewalling between the 2 subnets.